# Rudin Functional Analysis Chapter 6 Problem 13

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am having kind of a hard time with distributions and test functions and I am stuck with this problem now, any help would be really appreciated:

If $\phi \in D(\Omega) $ and $\Lambda \in D'(\Omega)$ does either of the statements $\phi \Lambda = 0$ and $\Lambda \phi = 0$ imply the other?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try with $\Lambda$ represented by a function $f \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$, ie. $\langle \Lambda, \phi \rangle = \int_\Omega f(x) \phi(x)dx$,  $\langle \phi\Lambda, \varphi \rangle = \langle \Lambda, \phi\varphi \rangle = \int_\Omega f(x) \phi(x)\varphi(x) dx\qquad$  (I guess Rudin chose this ugly notation to be consistent with the one in dual of Banach spaces)